# multiline replacement with new lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to change this multiline but I'm confused about how to do deal with new lines,

my file is like this

```
%nproc=1
%chk=pes.chk
#CCSD/6-31G* Opt=ModRedundant MaxDisk=50GB

Title

-1 1
H xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

I want to change it to this,

```
%nproc=20 
%chk=pes.chk 
%mem=200GB
#CCSD/6-31G(d) Opt SCF(maxcyc=1000)

Title

-1 1 
H xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

any simple way to replace the first 3 lines with the new 4 lines? also, the \n before "Title" is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
printf '%s\n' '%nproc=20' '%chk=pes.chk' '%mem=200GB' '#CCSD/6-31G(d) Opt SCF(maxcyc=1000)' |
  sed -e '3r/dev/stdin' -e '1,3d' file
```

or if the new lines are in a file named `linesfile`:

```
sed -e '3rlinesfile' -e '1,3d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `file1` is the file to modify (to replace first 3 lines with a block of 4 lines) and you have copied the 4 new lines into `file2`, I would do this:

```bsh
tail -n +4 file1 >> file2 && mv file2 file1
```

This is also efficient in case of a large `file1`, comparing to in-place editing commands.